# Confused with DNS pointing system

Tags: html, dns, subdomain, hosting, gatsby

**Overview**:

1. I have a static site made in react which is hosted on netlify.com https://rohan-punjani-portfolio.netlify.app
2. I already have a domain for myself http://dev-rohan.com
3. There exist a subdomain for dev-rohan.com http://k2.dev-rohan.com is already running

**What I want**

1. Is there any way to show my https://rohan-punjani-portfolio.netlify.app site on http://dev-rohan.com without disrupting my subdomain http://k2.dev-rohan.com.

**Extra Info:**

1. The Domain and the subdomain share the same parent root folder.
2. http://dev-rohan.com is made using simple HTML and CSS whereas https://rohan-punjani-portfolio.netlify.app is made in GatsbyJS (ReactJS as frontend)
3. The main domain is hosted in *hostinger*

Comment: Simply point the A record of `dev-rohan.com` at the netlify server, and the A record of `k2.dev-rohan.com` at whatever other server…?!

Comment: Seems like it will work! Great.. Thank you for the answer, it will figure out the rest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has the answer given by @deceze as a comment:
Simply point the A record of dev-rohan.com at the netlify server, and the A record of k2.dev-rohan.com at whatever other server…

Writing just not to have 0 answers when listing.